# Reference for comparison of heart cohomology with standard cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, homotopy-theory, derived-categories, triangulated-categories

I'm looking for a reference for the following fact (which I believe to be true and should be easy for people who understand how spectral sequences arise from filtrations).

> Let A,B be two hearts of bounded t-structures in a triangulated category D (which we may assume to be the homotopy category of a dg-category or $\pi_0$ of a stable $\infty$-category). Let E be an object.
>   Then there is an $E_2$ (or $E_1$?) spectral sequence $H^p_A( H^q_B(E)) \Rightarrow H_A^{p+q}(E)$ -- or possibly with $p$ and $q$ swapped on the LHS.

Where $H^i_\bullet$ is the cohomology with respect to the t-structure $\bullet$.
The point of the spectral sequence is that you can filter E in two ways, according to A or to B and then A.

Comment: I guess the right book where to find such a thing would have been Kashiwara-Schapira's "Cats and Shvs", but they don't like spectral sequences so they don't use them.

Answer (score 4):

The t-structure corresponding to $B$ will give you a filtration of any object $X$

$$
\ldots \to X_{-1} \to X_0 \to X_{1} \to \ldots
$$

such that the cofiber of the map $f_i: X_{i-1} \to X_i$ is equivalent to $H_B^i(X)[i]$.

Given any filtration of an object $X$ so that $ colim_i \, X_i \cong X$, under some hypotheses (stated below) you get a spectral sequence

$$
E_{r}^{p,q} \implies H_A^{p+q} colim_i \, X_i
$$

whose $E_1$ page is given by

$$
E_1^{p,q} \cong H_A^{p+q} cofib(f_p).
$$

The only hypotheses you need for this to hold are that the filtration $X_i$ is equivalent to the zero object for $i<<0$, and that the t-structure $A$ is compatible with sequential colimits. (This just means that the aisle $\mathcal{C}_A^{\leq 0}$ is stable under colimits of $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$-indexed diagrams.)

Comment: thanks. do you have a reference I can point to?

Comment: I learned this from Chapter I of Lurie's Higher Algebra, but there may be a better introduction for people interested in a less $\infty$-categorical setting....

Comment: I personally don't mind, but it's not to everyone's tastes... But maybe I can ask you a question: is there a simple way to rephrase the condition that the aisle be stable under colimits? And by rephrase I mean, say it in 1-categorical terms (like, it's closed under finite direct sums and taking cones).

Comment: Stable under sequential colimits: It just means that if you have some sequence of objects whose A-cohomology is concentrated in non-positive degrees (or non-negative, depending on grading; I always get this mixed up) then the colimit of these objects won't suddenly have cohomology in positive (or negative) grading.

Comment: A colimit in a triangulated category?

Comment: @FernandoMuro: I'm sure Hiro means $\infty$-colimit or homotopy colimit. That's why I was hoping he would decategorify it a bit. (or am I misunderstanding your cryptic remark?)

Comment: That's right; the colimit in the oo-category underlying your triangulated category. Almost all triangulated categories you deal with arise as the homotopy category of a stable oo-category.

Comment: @HiroLeeTanaka: usually it's the ordinary category which underlies the $\infty$-category :) I've edited the question to avoid those pathological triangulated categories, at the end of the day I'm interested in $D^b(CohX)$ for X smooth and projective over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what you mean by the ordinary category underlying the oo-category: For instance, a weak Kan complex doesn't have an underlying strict category. The only ways I know you obtain a strict category is by rigidifying to a Kan-complex category and passing to 0-simplices (which is not a construction invariant under equivalences) or by passing to the homotopy category. And, usually, the homotopy category is the thing that inherits a triangulated structure from the stability of the quasi-category.

Comment: (For instance, the triangulated category associated to $D^bCoh(X)$ is given by taking $H^0$ of the dg-category.)

Comment: I'm not an expert in the theory of quasi-categories. In my mind, any $\infty$-category has an associated ordinary category (which I think of as underlying the extra structure coming from higher morphisms). I think we are saying the same thing -- but thanks for the remark on weak Kan complexes.

Comment: @user: if you aren't thinking about the homotopy category, then the thing you are thinking about sounds like it won't be homotopically meaningful (that is, it won't be an operation on $\infty$-categories, in the same way that "the set of generators" is not an operation on groups). E.g. if you present an $\infty$-category as a topological category you can take the underlying sets of all of the Hom-spaces but this construction isn't invariant under replacing the Hom-spaces with homotopy equivalent spaces (compatibly with composition, etc.).

Comment: I *am* thinking about the homotopy category -- I just think of it as underlying the $\infty$-category, not the other way around. I'm sorry this is creating all this unnecessary confusion!

Comment: I guess it's a matter of taste, insofar as one can think that $\pi_0 X$ "underlies" a space $X$ itself. I wouldn't normally, but it's an interesting perspective; in derived algebra, one can sometimes think of higher homotopy groups of an algebra $A$ as "infinitesimal" directions associated to the ring $\pi_0 A$, so in some sense it does make sense to think of $A$ as underlied (underlaid?) by an actual affine scheme.

Comment: @HiroLeeTanaka: I just saw your last comment today. Absolutely, that's my point of view: a scheme is an honest space plus extra guff, same goes for $\infty$-categories. At least that's how I think about them :)

Comment: @HiroLeeTanaka: now, this is really coming quite a few months later... In your answer: is the cofiber of $f_p$ $H^p(X)[p]$ or $H^p(X)[-p]$? Also, is it really an $E_1$ spectral sequence? It's not an $E_2$ ss?